# What is the place of "say" between 2 direct speeches

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I read a book, and I see that:
"Oh - the black hat," **I say.** "No!" **says Shami**. "The blue hat is nicer." We watch and wait. In the end, the woman takes the blue hat. "Hurray!" **says Shami**.

‘Where is she?’ **Leon says** every day
‘Oh stop it, Leon,’ **says Shami.**

I want to know what is the situation to use "say + S" and "S + say"

Thank you

Comment: @vectory What do you find phonologically infelicitous about *said I* compared with something like *said Jack*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“He said, X” vs. “X, he said” vs. “X, said he”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92149/he-said-x-vs-x-he-said-vs-x-said-he)

Comment: You might use `said/says <noun>` when the verb is otherwise separated from the noun by a very long appositive: *" ... ," said Joe Biden, the President of the United States of America* is preferable to *" ... ," Joe Biden, the President of the United States of America, said*.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think, based on instincts not rules.

1. In general, noun-verb is more commonly the correct order in English than verb-noun.
2. But "says" seems a little different, if the object (what is said) comes before the noun and verb, as it does in all four Leon and Shaami examples above.  (The "blue hat is nicer" quotation is a separate sentence, independent of the "says Shami".)  In that situation, with the four proper-noun examples above, either "X says" or "says X" would be correct usage and the two are equivalent.

I would choose between them based on sound.  As one example, in the last line -- "‘Oh stop it, Leon,’ says Shami." -- if you used "Shami says" you would have the names Leon and Shami next to each other and it might sound weird or confusing, more so in spoken English than on the page.  Another consideration involving sound is whether you want variety among repeated phrases, in which case you would write it as above, mixing up both forms, or if you want consistency and parallelism and rhythm for some purpose, in which case you would write it differently.

3. That is not the case when the object (what is said) follows the noun and verb in the sentence.  There the typical noun-verb order rules.  So while I think that
   "Hurray!" says Shami.
   and
   "Hurray!" Shami says.
   both seem correct,
   Says Shami "Hurray!".
   seems wrong.  You would only say
   Shami says "Hurray!".
4. That is also not the case With personal pronouns.  "say/says I/you/he/she/it/we/they" sounds weird.  The "I say" in the first line would not normally be flipped to "say I".

Comment: _Says Shami "Hurray"_ may sound wrong to some, but Poe used this word order quite effectively in _The Raven_: Quoth the raven: "Nevermore".